# SharePoint Remote Event Receiver not working

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-on-prem, remote-event-receiver

**Platform**: Sharepoint on-premise

**Requirement**: To connect Remote Event Receiver to an existing list in the Host Web

**Problem**: Error in deploying Remote Event Receiver

[image]

**Details**:

- Created a new Provider Hosted App in Visual Studio By clicking File>New Project
- Went to Project Properties by pressing F4> **Handle App Installed=True** , **Handle App Unistalling=True**
- This automatically created AppEventReceiver.svc in my Project
- Right Clicked on the proj>Deploy. Then the error shown under title "Problem"
  above appears.

**AppManifest.xml & Web.Config**:

[image]

**One Solution I tried**:

Went to Project Properties by right clicking on "ProvHostedWeb".

Copied the URL under title "Project Url" and pasted it against ~remoteAppUrl in the AppManifest.xml file but it didn't work out. The app is still not getting deployed.

Answer (score 0):

From your `AppManifests.xml` (app principal `<Internal />`) it looks like you are trying to use remote event receiviers with SharePoint-hosted addin, which is not possible.

You need to switch your SharePoint project to provider hosted (double click on `AppManifest.xml` and change type in the drop-down):

[image]

Also make sure that in visual studio your web project is associated with SharePoint project. You can check this by left clicking on SharePoint project, then from VS top menu View->Properties Window (if nothing is selected, select your web project from drop down):
[image]